# How to add a generic Func<T, TResult> as a property to a class in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a little console application to track my progress working through interview prep questions.  I'd like the console app to iterate through all `Problems` and the `Solutions` that I've created.  The idea is that I have three classes:

```
class Problem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Type InputType { get; set; }

    public Type OutputType { get; set; }

    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public List<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }
}

class Solution
{
    public Func<object, object> SolutionFunc { get; set; }

    public List<string> Notes { get; set; }

    public int PerformanceInMs { get; set; }

}

class Test
{
    public object TestInput { get; set; }
    public object TestOutput { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to iterate through all `Problems`, find all `Solutions` that I've created, and then run `Tests` against them to give some handy insights into my progression as I improve my `Solutions` over time.

Right now I have the following:

```
    static List<Problem> problems = new List<Problem>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadProblems();
    }

    static void LoadProblems()
    {

        // todo: load from xml
        Problem testProblem = new Problem()
        {
            Title = "Test Problem",
            Description = "Return true if number is positive.",
            Solutions = new List<Solution>(),
            InputType = typeof(int),
            OutputType = typeof(bool),
            Tests = new List<Test>()
        };

        // todo: find better way to organize/dynamically load solutions and map to Problems
        testProblem.Solutions.Add(new Solution()
        {
            SolutionFunc = IsPositive1, // this is where I'm struggling
            Notes = new List<string>()
        });

        problems.Add(testProblem);

        return;
    }

    static bool IsPositive1(int testInput)
    {
        return testInput > 0;
    }
```

With the assumption that all `Problems` have only one input and output, I'd like to be able to assign `SolutionFunc = IsPositive1` above without typing the `SolutionFunc` property since the `InputType` and `OutputType` will change per `Problem`.

I don't know if the above assignment is a syntax issue or an issue with my overall approach here; how can I define a `Func<T,T>` property on a class where T is defined at time of instantiation?

Comment: How do you get your `Problem.InputType`? I suppose it's found by a type name? Or you always use `typeof(SomeClass)`?

Comment: _"I'm working on a little console application to track my progress working through interview prep questions. I'd like the console app to iterate through all Problems and the Solutions that I've created"_ -- all due respect...we don't care. Please simplify your question down to the _minimal_ amount of code required to illustrate your _specific_ issue. Do not distract us with narrative about the real-world scenario.

Comment: I suspect you have some misconceptions about generics... but as @PeterDuniho commented it is hard to see what exactly you have trouble with. Potentially `dynamic SolutionFunc` is an answer to your question, but it is hard to see what you actually expect this code would do.